# Adding extra functionality/logic to an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am new to Excel functions and VBA programming, so this problem has been a real challenge for me. I have a spreadsheet that keeps track of the status of applications in 64bit testing that I would like to add some extra functionality to.

This is what I need the function to do:

When an application is a "Yes" for retire (Adobe 1.0), it will take the value that is in the Retire Into UID (20) field and search the sheet for the application that has "20" in its UID field (Adobe 2.0). When it matches that UID, if Retire for Adobe 2.0 is "No" and Win7 x64 Fully Tested is "Pass", then I want to take the AD Group Name from that row (Adobe 2.0) and populate that into the Alternate column for Adobe 1.0. I also want to mark the Can Migrate to 64Bit cell as "Yes". If Win7 x64 Fully Tested for Adobe 2.0 is "Fail", the function will still populate the AD Group name in the Alternate field for Adobe 1.0, but Can Migrate to 64bit would be "No" for Adobe 1.0.

The full spreadsheet contains about 1800 items, so I would need it to be able to work through the entire document.

Here is a screenshot of the example data with the original data on the top table and what the result of the function will look like on the bottom table. Hopefully my explanation makes sense. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: example data]

Comment: This would be better asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), but in this form, you'd get my standard "Ask better" comment...

Comment: ... ***What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems fairly easy to do with IF() and VLOOKUP().  Have you tried those?  I'll give you a hint for the first part and then you can use that information to handle the second part.

Type this in H2:

=IF(F2="Yes",VLOOKUP(G2,A$2:B$nn,2,FALSE),"")

Here "nn" is the last row of your columns A & B.  You can fill this formula down by selecting H2, SHIFT-clicking on the last cell in column H, and choosing "Fill > Down" from the Edit menu.

Here's how this works: The IF() first checks to see if there's a "Yes" in F2.  If there is, it returns the result of VLOOKUP(). If not, it returns blank (""). The VLOOKUP() part looks for G2 (20 in this case) in column 1 of the range A$2:B$nn, and returns the corresponding value in column 2 of that range (Adobe 2.0). The penultimate "2" specifies the column to take the result from, and the FALSE specifies an exact match.

More information about VLOOKUP() can be found [on this support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

More information about IF() can be found [on this support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

Now you should be able to write a formula for cell I2 that will check whether F2 is "Yes" and then return "Yes" or "No" depending on whether L3 (Hint: row 10 of a lookup range) contains "Pass".

Try solving the second part, and check back here with questions if you run into problems. Good luck.

PS. There's a wrinkle here because your column I has some values that you don't want to overwrite when you fill the formula down.  This is a simple fix if it's true that everywhere column L has "Pass", column I has "Yes".  More on this later, but try to create a formula for this and post it in a comment or an edit to your question.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! Here are the results:

I used =IF(F2="Yes",VLOOKUP(G2,A$2:B$1800,2,FALSE),"") at H2
This brought in the AD group of the application that is superseding it perfectly.

I have a better understanding of how VLOOKUP works now.

For the next step, to determine if an application can migrate to 64bit (Column I) based on the test results (Column L) I used the function =IF(AND(F2="No",L2="Pass"),"Yes","No"). I may have to mess around with this one depending on how things need to be reported, but for now this is giving me the results I need.

Comment: Update: I updated the second formula to add the more specific functionality I'm looking for.

If a retired application's successor is "Pass" for Win7 x64 Fully Tested, then it will be marked "Yes" for Can Migrate to 64Bit. If an application is not marked to retire, but Win7 x64 Fully Tested is "Pass", Can Migrate to 64Bit for that application will still be marked "Yes".

Formula:
=IF(OR(IF(F2="Yes",VLOOKUP(G2,A$2:L$10,12,FALSE),"")="Pass",L2="Pass",)=TRUE,"Yes","No")

Comment: Very good! Glad this is working for you and glad to have helped.